# How do I update signing key for an old app?

Tags: android, google-play

I have an app that's been on the Android market since pretty much the beginning. I'm now seeing this warning from keytool:

```
<efalk> uses the SHA1withDSA signature algorithm which is considered a security risk. This algorithm will be disabled in a future update.
<efalk> uses a 1024-bit DSA key which is considered a security risk. This key size will be disabled in a future update.
```

Can I just generate a new key and start signing with that, or is there something else I need to do to keep publishing my app?

Comment: You can't change the signing key of an app-  doing so will break all updates-  updates require the signature to use the same key, to prove its a legit update.

Now if you use Google Play Signing, you can change the key you use to update to Google Play.  But you can't update the key used to sign the apk sent to the device.

Comment: OK, thanks, that's what I thought. I guess I'll just wait to see if jarsigner breaks in the future, and deal with it then. Make your comment an answer, and I'll mark it as the solution.

Comment: Check out the information about signing key rotation: https://source.android.com/security/apksigning/v3?hl=en

Comment: Yeah, I've been fighting the stupid system all day. It *really* wants me to switch to Android App Bundle and Play App Signing, so I've decided to go ahead and bite the bullet.